# Googlemock not catching leaked object

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, googletest, googlemock

I created a googlemock text fixture class, and in the SetUp I'm creating two objects with `new`. In the teardown, if I delete none I only get the memory leak error for one of the objects.

```
class MissileLauncherListenerTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
    MissileLauncher* launcher;
    MockProjectileCreatorListener* launcher_listener;

    virtual void SetUp() {
        launcher = new MissileLauncher(FRIENDLY) ;
        launcher_listener = new MockProjectileCreatorListener();
        launcher->add_listener(launcher_listener);
    }

    virtual void TearDown() {
        delete launcher_listener;
    }
};

TEST_F(MissileLauncherListenerTest, multiple_listeners_notified) {
    MockProjectileCreatorListener launcher_listener2;

    EXPECT_CALL(*launcher_listener, notify_projectile_launched(_, _));
    EXPECT_CALL(launcher_listener2, notify_projectile_launched(_, _));

    launcher->add_listener(&launcher_listener2);
    launcher->create_missile(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

In this code, I get no memory leak errors from googletest, shouldn't I be receiving one for `MissileLauncher`?

Comment: As Marko Popovic says, gmock doesn't support memory leaks detection for the overall test application, it just tracks mock objects. If you want to detect memory leaks you should run your test application over [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or, alternatively, use a testing framework with leak detection support like [CppUTest](http://cpputest.github.io/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not receiving a memory leak error for `MissileLauncher` object because it is not a mock object. It is an object of your class, so `gmock` will not track any leaks. On the other hand, class `MockProjectileCreatorListener` is generated by `gmock`. Therefore, all objects of this class are mock objects and `gmock` mechanisms will warn you about leakage of such objects.

Comment: Thank you, so in best interests of good code, should I be deleting the missile launcher even if not deleting doesn't cause any errors?

Comment: @JeLLyB0x3r Yes, I believe you should strive to eliminate memory leaks even in cases like this. Although these leaks will not be present in production code, they can still cause problems if you have large objects and test suites that span hundreds or even thousands of unit tests.